# PrimeNG dropdown selected item data binding

Tags: typescript, angular, primeng

I am simply trying to bind data from a dropdown menu with `ngModel`.  There is an error I receive when the app loads that makes some sense.

```
browser_adapter.js:84 EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''
```

This leads me to believe that the error is stemming from the fact that `ngModel` is not initially bound with any data when the app loads.

I'm not the best at using Observables... so beware.

**Partial of the html dropdown**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="actionsToTake" (onChange)="onToggleCreateActionInput()" 
  [(ngModel)]="action"></p-dropdown>
```

**Relevant TypeScript (excluded imports)**

```
export class ActionView {
  public actionsToTake: SelectItem[] = [];
  public action: Action = new Action();

  constructor (private actionCreateService: ActionCreateService) {
    // populate dropdown list (actionsToTake) with data from service call
    this.actionCreateService.getActionFields().subscribe((resp) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < resp.data.data.actionElm.length; i++) {
        this.actionsToTake.push({label: resp.data.data.actionElm[i].name,
          value: resp.data.data.actionElm[i].name});
      }
    });
  }

  public onToggleCreateActionInput = (action): void => {
    // test if something in "action" exists, and then do something based on that
  };
}
```

So, when the app initially loads, `action` is empty.  I would expect that an empty value bound to `ngModel` wouldn't break the app, but maybe I am misinterpreting the error.  Ultimately I want the selected item to be bound, and I think getting past this error will get me to that point.

Comment: Which version of angular router and forms are you using?

Comment: Router 3.0.0-beta.1 and Forms 0.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was somewhere in the middle between using the deprecated Angular forms and the new Angular forms.  To use PrimeNG, upgrade to the new forms and include this in your application's bootstrap:

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(App, [
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms()
]);
```

Then, in my parent component where I instantiate the form, I had to change the imports from:

```
import {NgForm, FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
```

to

```
import {NgForm, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgModel} from '@angular/forms';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
```

In the child component, these imports aren't needed.  You need to include `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` wherever `[(ngModel)]` is. So, in my case:

```
<p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="actions" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't test it yet, but from what I've read it seems that you'll have to update your app to use the new forms and disable the old deprecated version.

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
]);
```

Related resources
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/549#issuecomment-230305403

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=46115&p=144059&hilit=no+value+accessor+for#p144059

EDIT!

For nested components you'll have to implement a Control Value Accessor inside the child component in order to allow the parent component to take control over it.
I have an example where I implement a custom toggle component, but this component also uses prime ng toggle component.

This is how the child component looks like:

```js
import {Component,Input, Provider, forwardRef} from '@angular/core'
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';

import {ToggleButton} from 'primeng/primeng'

const noop = () => {};

const CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomToggle),
        multi: true
    });

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-toggle',
    template: `<span>
                  <p-toggleButton
                     [(ngModel)]="value"   >
                  </p-toggleButton>
               </span>`,
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES,ToggleButton],
    providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})

export class CustomToggle implements ControlValueAccessor {           
           
    private _value: string;
    
    private _onTouchedCallback: (_:any) => void = noop;
    private _onChangeCallback: (_:any) => void = noop;
    
    get value(): any { return this._value};
    
    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this._value) {
            this._value = v;
            this._onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }
    
    onTouched() {
        this._onChangeCallback;
    }
    
    writeValue(value: any) {
        this._value = value;
    }
    
    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this._onChangeCallback = fn;
    }
    
    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this._onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }
    
}
```

And this is how it can be used inside parent components

```
<custom-toggle [(ngModel)]="myToggle"  ></custom-toggle>
```

Where myToggle is just a boolean variable.

More on how to implement a control value accessor:
http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel

Comment: It seems like there's a "nesting" issue.  I'm trying to inject one component into another.  The parent component has a form. The other component (the one outlined in this post) is being injected into that form.  Now I'm getting `If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions`.  Even after making the suggested changes, the same error persists.

Comment: So the dropdown is inside the child component. Right?

Like Parent>Child>dropdown  ?

Comment: I have edit my answer with something I think could be a solution. Take a look.

Comment: I solved my issue after properly configuring everything with the new angular forms.  I was originally using Bootstrap and was using deprecated angular forms.  Then I switched to Prime, which uses the new forms.  I then had to fix my parent component's imports.  Thank you for your help.